# python:why whis code only loop one time?

Tags: python-2.7, loops

I tend read two csv files and print specific column by key name.
First, I have a list of my key name like `key = [a,b,c]`

and I these following code:

```
with open('./file/report.csv', 'rb') as csvfile,open('./file/all.csv','rb') as csvfile2:
    reader2 = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    reader3 = csv.DictReader(csvfile2)
    for i in key:
         for row in reader2: 
             for row2 in reader3:
                 if row['Case Id'] == i and row2['name'] == i:
                     a=row['Status']
                     b = row2['result']
                     print a,b
```

two csv files:

```
report.csv:                         all.csv:        
Case Id       Status                 name           result   
  a             111                   a               1111
  b             222                   b               2222
  c             333                   c               3333
```

my expected result is it will loop three times because there are three elements in `key` list.expected result should look like:

```
111 1111
222 2222
333 3333
```

But actual result is:

```
111 1111
```

it only loop one time. I am new on coding things, need some help! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Readers are one-time iterators and are depleted after one iteration.

This means that in the second time around you don't have anything in `reader3` since you've already depleted it.

Try this:

```
reader2 = list(csv.DictReader(csvfile)) # optional
reader3 = list(csv.DictReader(csvfile2)) # must
```

If you're using big files use more sophisticated matching or just re-open the file each time.

Answer (score 0):

Think of a `CVSReader` as a one-time iterator over the file. Once you read a line, you cannot go back, and one the reader is exhausted, you cannot read any more data from the file without re-creating it. A good practice would be to read both readers in to memory and then going over them. E.g.:

```
list2 = list(reader2);
list3 = list(reader3);

for i in key:
     for row in list2: 
         for row2 in list3:
             if row['Case Id'] == i and row2['name'] == i:
                 a=row['Status']
                 b = row2['result']
                 print a,b
```